# Visual Studio Code scroll back buffer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to control how many lines can be in the scroll back buffer?

I need a few thousand lines. I'm writing testing code and have extensive output going to a log, but I have simple pass / fail results to the console.

The validations for each test print to the console. I may have 150 to 250 tests per suite, but say 8+ validations per test. I'd rather *not* open a full terminal window as this integrated environment is cleaning up my screen quite a bit.

Comment: Hi @Keith if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: For fun you can see [Setting to control the terminal's buffer size #19262](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19262)

Answer (score 573, accepted):

1. Open preferences

   1. *File* / *Code (Mac)* → *Preferences* → *Settings*.
   2. Ctrl / Cmd (Mac) + Shift + P → search for `preferences`
2. Search for `scrollback`.
3. Overwrite `"terminal.integrated.scrollback": 1000,` with whatever you want, e.g. `1000000`.

Comment: Is there a way to set it to _infinite_?

Comment: Looks like it can't be set to infinite by design - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63452#issuecomment-441796199

Comment: Or pipe the output like this `npm run test 2>&1| tee test-output.txt`

Comment: in VSCode --> Ctrl + SHIFT + P --> type: settings --> click: "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" --> add: `"terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,`  to increase default by x10 :-)

Comment: This does not change the scrollback size of debug console window, I set it to 1000000, the scrollback of console debug is still about 10000 lines. How to change the debug console scrollback size?

Comment: At step 1, In my VS Code, there is no File → Preferences. Instead, click on the cog wheel at bottom left of window, and click on Settings.

Comment: Adding to @Jonny comment, you can also go to Code → Preferences → Settings.

Answer (score 35):

here is how i solved it:

ps: remember to open a new terminal for changes to take effect:

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I think this is a setting of the terminal application you are using, e.g. Terminal.app on OS X or (default) [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) on Linux. If you modify the scrollback limit in those applications it should be reflected in Visual Studio Code.

I opened this to ask the Visual Studio Code guys for verification: *[Integrated terminal unlimited buffer #14320](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14320)*

Comment: should be - but it is not.

Comment: this is indeed very incorrect since vscode verified they use their own terminal emulator. should I go ahead and delete this answer? not sure what the practice is here as a n00b SO user.

Comment: I downvoted it to make the score negative which usually serves a sign to not do a thing. Maybe deletion isn't needed -- your answer and associated score may be instructive to future users who read the accepted answer and think for a second they might try to outsmart it (like me)